# Select Rows with min value for each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a database with a table that look like this:

| Date | Container ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1 | 1 |
| 2/2 | 1 |
| 3/3 | 1 |
| 4/4 | 2 |
| 5/5 | 2 |
| 6/6 | 3 |
| 7/7 | 3 |

Container ID is a foreign key to another table and the containers are effectively named groups that elements can be part of.

I'm looking to write a query that gets the earliest date for each `Container ID` like this:

| Earliest Date | Container ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1 | 1 |
| 4/4 | 2 |
| 6/6 | 3 |

Is there some way I can join on Container ID to make this happen or am I on the wrong path with joins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But the best would be save dates as date column. The you can use all function for dates

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   [Date]  varchar(10),
>   [Container ID] INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   ([Date], [Container ID])
> VALUES
>   ('1/1', '1'),
>   ('2/2', '1'),
>   ('3/3', '1'),
>   ('4/4', '2'),
>   ('5/5', '2'),
>   ('6/6', '3'),
>   ('7/7', '3');
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT MIN([Date]), [Container ID] FROM table1 GROUP BY [Container ID]
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> (No column name) | Container ID
> :--------------- | -----------:
> 1/1              |            1
> 4/4              |            2
> 6/6              |            3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=773bd85f4f0f7b27015945a5f6eff44d)*

Comment: this is NOT selecting the row with the min-value but just showing the min value per group. add another column with unique values and you will see the issue.

Comment: this works only with two columns, three columns will not show the corrrect result, because result set are not sorted, so with three columns or more  you need row_number or similar window functions, please don't spam answers, make qa new question tag it with sql and i will see it and explain in detail, why you are wrong

Comment: thats what I mean. the question is about "selecting the row", not a single value.

Comment: Like I alreadY said there are hundreds of thread TT hat explains that my so find them or ask your own Question . From Nd for example row number

Answer (score 2):

Just another option using `WITH TIES`

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order By row_number() over (partition by ContainerID Order by Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `group by` and `min()`:

```
select id, min(date)
from t
group by id;
```

As a note:  You could also use `join`, but it is a bit more arcane:

```
select t.*
from t left join
     t t2
     on t.id = t2.id and t2.date < t.date
where t2.id is null;
```

The `left join` is matching to rows that have a smaller date.  The smallest date (per id) is the one with no matching rows.

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate, right Gordon?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used a date column but you can adjust yours to suit

```
CREATE TABLE DAta (Date_example VARCHAR(50), ContainerID INT)

INSERT INTO DAta (Date_example, ContainerID)
VALUES ('1a', 1)

INSERT INTO DAta (Date_example, ContainerID)
VALUES ('2a', 1)

INSERT INTO DAta (Date_example, ContainerID)
VALUES ('3a', 1)

INSERT INTO DAta (Date_example, ContainerID)
VALUES ('1b', 2)

INSERT INTO DAta (Date_example, ContainerID)
VALUES ('2b', 2)

INSERT INTO DAta (Date_example, ContainerID)
VALUES ('3b', 2)

INSERT INTO DAta (Date_example, ContainerID)
VALUES ('1c', 3)

INSERT INTO DAta (Date_example, ContainerID)
VALUES ('2c', 3)

INSERT INTO DAta (Date_example, ContainerID)
VALUES ('3c', 3)
```

**The resulting table is:**

```
+---------------+-------------+
| Date_example  | ContainerID |
+---------------+-------------+
| 1a            |           1 |
| 2a            |           1 |
| 3a            |           1 |
| 1b            |           2 |
| 2b            |           2 |
| 3b            |           2 |
| 1c            |           3 |
| 2c            |           3 |
| 3c            |           3 |
+---------------+-------------+
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DATE_EXAMPLE
        ,CONTAINERID
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY CONTAINERID ORDER BY CONTAINERID
            ) ROW_NUM
    FROM DATA
    ) A
WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
+---------------+--------------+---------+
| date_example  | containerID  | row_num |
+---------------+--------------+---------+
| 1a            |           1  |       1 |
| 1b            |           2  |       1 |
| 1c            |           3  |       1 |
+---------------+--------------+---------+
```